# matrix %in% matrix

Tags: r

Suppose I have two matrices, each with two columns and differing numbers of row. I want to check and see which pairs of one matrix are in the other matrix. If these were one-dimensional, I would normally just do `a %in% x` to get my results. `match` seems only to work on vectors.

```
> a
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    4    9
[3,]    1    6
[4,]    7    7
> x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

I would like the result to be `c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)`.

Comment: I actually asked a very similar question. You can check the answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316946/comparing-rows-between-two-matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316946/comparing-rows-between-two-matrices) The solution by Matthew Dowle using data.table is extremely elegant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another approach would be:

```
> paste(a[,1], a[,2], sep="$$") %in% paste(x[,1], x[,2], sep="$$")
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

A more general version of this is:

```
> apply(a, 1, paste, collapse="$$") %in% apply(x, 1, paste, collapse="$$")
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Ok, call me stupid -- what does the "$$" separator do, or did you simply pick a character set guaranteed not to look like an element of a or x ?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. This is the most intuitive to me, although it does seem a little like cheating :). Carl, yes you are right that there is nothing special about "$$" as long as it is not an element of `a` or `x`. But note that nothing is ever "guaranteed" to not be in any matrix that this function operates on. So it's probably a good idea to check that "$$" is not in the matrix. You could do this by making sure both matrices are numeric with `is.numeric()` or you can check more explicitly with `grepl("\\$\\$",a)`. Actually, I think you only need to check one, right?

Comment: Thanks XW.  I think I'll use the infamous "_" to join values :-)

Comment: Xu Wang: rather than "cheating" I think the word you are looking for is "kludgy".

Answer (score 12):

Recreate your data:

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 7), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
x <- matrix(c(1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Define a function `%inm%` that is a matrix analogue to `%in%`:

```
`%inm%` <- function(x, matrix){
  test <- apply(matrix, 1, `==`, x)
  any(apply(test, 2, all))
}
```

Apply this to your data:

```
apply(a, 1, `%inm%`, x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

To compare a single row:

```
a[1, ] %inm% x
[1] FALSE

a[2, ] %inm% x
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You can also use `identical`, eg : `%inm%` <- function(x,matrix){ 
  apply(x,1,function(i){
    any(apply(matrix,1,identical,i))
  })
}

Comment: thank you Andrie! Thanks also for using a `%inm%` type operator, which is what I wanted to do. And thank you Joris for the suggestion to use `identical`. I'm learning a lot from reading all of your solutions, Andrie and Joris!

Comment: Andrie, any thoughts on my new speed test?

Answer (score 10):

Andrie's solution is perfectly fine. But if you have big matrices, you might want to try something else, based on recursion. If you work columnwise, you can cut down on the calculation time by excluding everything that doesn't match at the first position:

```
fastercheck <- function(x,matrix){
  nc <- ncol(matrix)
  rec.check <- function(r,i,id){
    id[id] <- matrix[id,i] %in% r[i]
    if(i<nc & any(id)) rec.check(r,i+1,id) else any(id)
  }
  apply(x,1,rec.check,1,rep(TRUE,nrow(matrix)))
}
```

The comparison :

```
> set.seed(100)
> x <- matrix(runif(1e6),ncol=10)
> a <- matrix(runif(300),ncol=10)
> a[c(3,7,9,15),] <- x[c(1000,48213,867,20459),]
> system.time(res1 <- a %inm% x)
   user  system elapsed 
  31.16    0.14   31.50 
> system.time(res2 <- fastercheck(a,x))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.37    0.00    0.38 
> identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE
> which(res2)
[1]  3  7  9 15
```

EDIT:

I checked the accepted answer just for fun. Performs better than the double apply ( as you get rid of the inner loop), but recursion still rules! ;-)

```
> system.time(apply(a, 1, paste, collapse="$$") %in% 
 + apply(x, 1, paste, collapse="$$"))
   user  system elapsed 
   6.40    0.01    6.41
```

Comment: This is cool, thank you Joris. I really like recursive functions!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach using the `digest` package and creating `checksums` for each row, which are generated using a hashing algorithm (the default being `md5`)

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 7, 7), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
x <- matrix(c(1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
apply(a, 1, digest) %in% apply(x, 1, digest)

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: what a **creative** and concise solution! Thank you very much, I like this one!

Comment: Any thoughts on my speed test?

Answer (score 1):

Coming in late to the game: I had previously written an algorithm using the "paste with delimiter" method, and then found this page.  I was guessing that one of the code snippets here would be the fastest, but:

```
andrie<-function(mfoo,nfoo) apply(mfoo, 1, `%inm%`, nfoo)
# using Andrie's %inm% operator exactly as above
carl<-function(mfoo,nfoo) {
 allrows<-unlist(sapply(1:nrow(mfoo),function(j) paste(mfoo[j,],collapse='_'))) 
 allfoo <- unlist(sapply(1:nrow(nfoo),function(j) paste(nfoo[j,],collapse='_')))
 thewalls<-setdiff(allrows,allfoo)
 dowalls<-mfoo[allrows%in%thewalls,]
}

 ramnath <- function (a,x) apply(a, 1, digest) %in% apply(x, 1, digest)

 mfoo<-matrix( sample(1:100,400,rep=TRUE),nr=100)
 nfoo<-mfoo[sample(1:100,60),]

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(andrie(mfoo,nfoo),carl(mfoo,nfoo),ramnath(mfoo,nfoo),times=5)

Unit: milliseconds
                expr       min        lq    median        uq            max neval
  andrie(mfoo, nfoo) 25.564196 26.527632 27.964448 29.687344     102.802004     5
    carl(mfoo, nfoo)  1.020310  1.079323  1.096855  1.193926       1.246523     5
 ramnath(mfoo, nfoo)  8.176164  8.429318  8.539644  9.258480       9.458608     5
```

So apparently constructing character strings and doing a single set operation is fastest!
(PS I checked and all 3 algorithms give the same result)