# determine which row a vector in a matrix using R function

Tags: r, matrix

e.g.

```
a1 <- rbind(c(1,3), c(1,2))
A1 <- rbind(c(1, 2), c(1, 4), c(1,3), c(2, 4))
```

I want to check a1 in which row of A1.
In this example, the return value should be c(3, 1).

Comment: A very fast data table answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316946/comparing-rows-between-two-matrices). Also a duplicate question, but since that's the only good answer I will not mark as duplicate.  Maybe that question should be marked as a dupe of this one.

Comment: `which(duplicated(rbind(A1, a1), fromLast=TRUE))` is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for not testing the earlier solution, I hope this works for you:

```
options(stringsAsFactors =F)

a11 <- do.call("paste0",data.frame(a1))
A11 <- do.call("paste0", data.frame(A1))
which(A11 %in% a11)
```

**Output**:

```
> a11
[1] "13" "12"
> A11
[1] "12" "14" "13" "24"
> which(A11 %in% a11)
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: @PoGibas, It wasn't working for different scenarios, I found a few where the sum was not coming 2 however the values where matching, I feel terrible now.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `apply` and `duplicated`. The idea is to use `apply` a loop through every row in `A1` with a function `rbind` each row to `a1`, and the use `duplicated` and `any` to check if there are any duplicates.

```
which(apply(A1, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(rbind(x, a1)))))
# [1] 1 3
```

Or we can combine all the numbers to string and match the strings from `A1` and `a1`. This solution is inspired by PKumar's solution.

```
which(apply(A1, 1, toString) %in% apply(a1, 1, toString))
# [1] 1 3
```

#### Test the approach

In the comment section of Dror Bogin's answer, the OP proposed a solution, which is `which(duplicated(rbind(a1 ,A1))) - nrow(a1)`. This solution works only if there are no duplicates in the large matrix, such as `A1`.

For example, considering the following matrix, `A2`, which is the same as `A1` except three extra rows with two of them are duplicates.

```
A2 <- rbind(c(1, 2), c(1, 4), c(1, 3), c(2, 4), c(5, 8), c(4, 3), c(5, 8))
```

The expected output of `A2` should also be `c(1, 3)`. However, when we used OP's solution, we will get an extra index at 7.

```
which(duplicated(rbind(a1 ,A2)))-nrow(a1) 
# [1] 1 3 7
```

But my solution will still return `c(1, 3)`.

```
which(apply(A2, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(rbind(x, a1)))))
# [1] 1 3
```

Finally, if OP is certain that there are no any duplicates. We can use the following code to further simplify the code.

```
which(duplicated(rbind(A1, a1), fromLast = TRUE))
# [1] 1 3
```

#### Performance Evaluation

Since the OP mentions that the real-world matrix is huge, it is worthy of conducting a performance evaluation of all the proposed methods here.

So far we have a total of five methods.

Method 1: The "apply-duplicate" method I proposed.

Method 2: The "apply-toString-match" method inspired by PKumar

Method 3: The "do.call-dataframe-match" method PKumar proposed

Method 4: The "for-loop" method Dror Bogin proposed

Method 5: The "data.table" method tophcito proposed

Below I used the `microbenchmark` package to conduct performance evaluation.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

microbenchmark(m1 = {which(apply(A1, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(rbind(x, a1)))))},
               m2 = {which(apply(A1, 1, toString) %in% apply(a1, 1, toString))},
               m3 = {which(do.call("paste0",data.frame(A1)) %in% do.call("paste0",data.frame(a1)))},
               m4 = {v1 = vector()
               for(i in 1:nrow(A1)){
                 b = ifelse(all(a1[1,] == A1[i,]),i,NA)
                 d = ifelse(all(a1[2,] == A1[i,]),i,NA)
                 v1 = c(v1,b,d)
               }
               v1[!is.na(v1)]},
               m5 = {a1_dt <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(a1))
               A1_dt <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(A1))
               setnames(a1_dt, c("x", "y"))
               setnames(A1_dt, c("x", "y"))
               A1_dt[, id := 1:nrow(A1_dt)]
               result <- merge(A1_dt, a1_dt, by = c("x", "y"))
               result[, id]})

# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#   m1  164.498  191.7435  235.6025  215.1320  237.751 1777.094   100
#   m2   71.968   82.2490  101.0790   99.2130  112.064  202.024   100
#   m3  140.851  165.5265  197.3618  185.3175  206.908  395.824   100
#   m4 4734.462 5107.4095 5450.1260 5348.2450 5535.876 8807.847   100
#   m5 1286.684 1394.6360 1591.3651 1508.7560 1674.283 4361.256   100
```

The results show that Method 2 is the fastest and Method 3 is the second fastest. It makes sense that Method 2 should be faster than Method 3 because converting object from matrix to data frame takes some time. Method 1 ranked as the third place, which is still considered to be an approach with good performance in my opinion. Method 5 is slower than the above-mentioned three methods, indicating that although `data.table` is designed to handle large data frame, in this case there is no need to conduct the operation using `data.table`. Finally, Method 4 is the slowest, showing for-loop is inefficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a variable for each row you want to check in *a1*:

```
a1 <- rbind(c(1,3), c(1,2))
A1 <- rbind(c(1, 2), c(1, 4), c(1,3), c(2, 4))
v1 = vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(A1)){
  b = ifelse(all(a1[1,] == A1[i,]),i,NA)
  d = ifelse(all(a1[2,] == A1[i,]),i,NA)
  v1 = c(v1,b,d)
}
v1 = v1[!is.na(v1)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Since I have a large matrix, using a loop method is a little bit time expensive.

Comment: which of the matrices is too large?

Comment: A1 matrices is very large.

Comment: if the matrix you are searching in, is very large it should be fine. why not just run the code and let it run for as long as it needs?   if you want it to run faster then use an apply variant.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem using which(duplicated(rbind(a1 ,A1)))-nrow(a1)

Comment: @shuquanliu I think your solution is good if there are no any duplicates in A1 before you combine a1 and A1, if there are duplicates in A1, your approach will return extra index that does not match with a1. Please see and test my answer to see if my answer works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `%in%` and `rowSums` (should be a way to improve it):

```
apply(a1, 1, 
      function(x) which(rowSums(matrix(A1 %in% x, ncol = 2)) == 2))
```

Another possibility would be to use `rowMeans` and `== 1`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution entails adding row numbers and merging the two matrices as data tables. The advantage is that data tables are optimized for speed and large data.

First, convert your two matrices to data tables:

```
library(data.table)
a1 <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(a1))
A1 <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(A1))
setnames(a1, c("x", "y"))
setnames(A1, c("x", "y"))
```

Let's add an additional column with the rownumbers:

```
A1[, id := 1:nrow(A1)]
```

Finally, we merge the two tables (which will return the rows of `A1` where values from `a1` appear in):

```
result <- merge(A1, a1, by = c("x", "y"))
```

As you are only interested in the row numbers, let's select just that:

```
result[, id]
```