# Is there a %in% operator across multiple columns

Tags: r, unique, paste

Imagine you have two data frames

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 3), v2 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 2), v2 = c("b", "b", "c"))
```

Here's what they look like, side by side:

```
> cbind(df1, df2)
  V1 v2 V1 v2
1  1  a  1  b
2  2  b  2  b
3  3  c  2  c
```

You want to know which observations are duplicates, across *all variables*.

This can be done by pasting the cols together and then using %in%:

```
df1Vec <- apply(df1, 1, paste, collapse= "")
df2Vec <- apply(df2, 1, paste, collapse= "")
df2Vec %in% df1Vec
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The second observation is thus the only one in df2 and also in df1.

Is there no faster way of generating this output - something like %IN%, which is %in% across multiple variables, or should we just be content with the apply(paste) solution?

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414368/r-tuple-in-operator) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943695/matrix-in-matrix) do these answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would go with

```
interaction(df2) %in% interaction(df1)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can wrap it in a binary operator:

```
"%IN%" <- function(x, y) interaction(x) %in% interaction(y)
```

Then

```
df2 %IN% df1
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

rbind(df2, df2) %IN% df1
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Disclaimer: I have somewhat modified my answer from a previous one that was using `do.call(paste, ...)` instead of `interaction(...)`. Consult the history if you like. I think that Arun's claims about "terrible inefficiency" (a bit extreme IMHO) still hold but if you like a concise solution that uses base R only and is fast-ish with small-ish data that's probably it.

Comment: Concise, works and uses a neat little function (interaction) that I've never seen before. You guys R R machines! Many thanks for helping out and making R such an awesome language to use. Next stage: rewrite my horrible code and spread the word (I'm writing code for use by academics but need to get MUCH better at coding before thinking about creating a package).

Answer (score 4):

Calling `duplicated` on a `data.frame` or using `paste` coerces all columns to character type, which is *terribly* inefficient as the data size gets bigger. `duplicated.data.table` method does *not* coerce them to characters and is therefore quite efficient and scales well.

Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
`%dtIN%` <- function(y, x) {
    tmp = rbindlist(list(x,y))
    len_ = nrow(x)
    tmp[, idx := any(.I <= len_) & .N > 1L, by=names(tmp)]
    tail(tmp$idx, nrow(y))
}

# example:
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 3), v2 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), v2 = c("b", "b", "b", "c", "b"))

df2 %dtIN% df1
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

#### Benchmarks:

@flodel's (earlier) benchmark is nice (see history), but doesn't really showcase the true effects of this unnecessary coercion, because the entire data size is:

```
print(object.size(df1), units="Kb") # 783.8 Kb
```

*less than 1 MB*. Let's construct a little bigger data set to see the effect.

#### First benchmark:

```
set.seed(45L)
df1 <- data.frame(x=sample(paste0("V", 1:1000), 1e7, TRUE), 
                  y = sample(1e2, 1e7, TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(x=sample(paste0("V", 1:700), 1e6, TRUE),
                  y=sample(1e2, 1e6, TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


print(object.size(df1), units="Mb") # 114.5Mb

system.time(ans1 <- df2 %dtIN% df1)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.896   0.296   2.265 

system.time(ans2 <- df2 %IN% df1)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 13.014   0.510  14.417 

identical(ans1, ans2) # [1] TRUE
```

Flodel's solution is ~6.3x slower here.

#### Second benchmark:

Here's another example to try and convince that it really is terribly inefficient ;):

```
set.seed(1L)
DF1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1e7), y=sample(letters, 1e7, TRUE))
DF2 <- data.frame(x=sample(DF1$x, 1e5, TRUE), y=sample(letters, 1e5, TRUE))

require(data.table)
system.time(ans1 <- DF2 %dtIN% DF1)
#    user  system elapsed 
#  35.024   0.884  37.225 

system.time(ans2 <- DF2 %IN% DF1)   ## flodel's earlier answer
#    user  system elapsed 
# 312.931   2.591 319.652
```

That's 1/2 a minute vs 5 minutes on only 1 numeric column, ~8.6x. Now who wants to add another numeric column to it and try again :)?

IIUC, @flodel's new solution using `interaction` shouldn't be much different because, it still stores them as "factors", where the factor levels have to be characters..

But this one actually started swapping...

```
system.time(ans3 <- interaction(DF2) %in% interaction(DF1))
## Had to stop after ~3 min because it took 5.5GB and started to SWAP.
```

Comment: The base equivalent: `tail(duplicated(rbind(df1, df2)), nrow(df2))`. Let's note that it assumes `df2` has no duplicates.

Comment: @flodel, except that `base:::duplicated` will *paste* all the columns together (which means, coercing to character), which is the same as what the OP has done.

Comment: Why are you concerned about paste and coercion to character?

Comment: Because it's just a waste of time, the time spent on coercion.