# R match/%in% for data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to find those rows in a data frame, which appear in another data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c(0,1,1,1), V2=c(0,1,0,2))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c(0,1), V2=c(0,1))

in_df(df1, df2) # should yield c(T, T, F, F)
```

Is there a function which calculates this?

Comment: [some more solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943695/matrix-in-matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
as.character(interaction(df1)) %in% as.character(interaction(df2))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `duplicated.data.frame` method that can be combined with `rbind`:

```
in_df <- function(d1,d2) duplicated(rbind(d2,d1))[-(1:nrow(d2)) ]
in_df(df1, df2)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```